# Dividing people into groups of 4

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$\textbf{Q1: }$ A class consisting of 4 grad and 12 undergrad students is randomly divided into four groups of 4 each. What is the probability that each group includes a grad student?

My attempt: $$P = \frac{ \left( \binom{4}{1}\binom{12}{3}\right) \left( \binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{3}\right)\left( \binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{3}\right)\left( \binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{3}\right) }{\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}}$$

$\textbf{Q2: }$ Same question as above but with $n$ grad students and $16 - n$ undergrad, what is the probability each group includes a grad student? Of course, $n \geq 4$?

My attempt:

$$P = \frac{   \text{something}  }{\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}} $$

$$\text{something} = \underbrace{\left(\binom{n}{1}\binom{n - 1}{1}\binom{n-2}{1}\binom{n-3}{1} \right)}_{(\text{T1})} \, \, \underbrace{\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}}_{(\text{T2})}$$

where $\text{T1}$ I think first assigns each grad student to each group and $\text{T2}$ assigns everyone else.

Please let me know if this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to Q1 is correct. The answer to Q2 is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s say that the teacher cannot differentiate graduate students and undergraduate student, so he just divide everyone into group of $4$. Define $A_{i}$ as “there is no graduate student in group $i$“.

$$
P(A_{i})=\frac{\binom{12}{n}}{\binom{16}{n}}
$$

Since if a group does not have any graduate student, then all $n$ graduate students are among $12$ students who are not member of that group, instead of among all $16$ students.

Similarly,

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A_{i}\cap A_{j})&=\frac{\binom{8}{n}}{\binom{16}{n}}\\
\\
P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{k})&=\frac{\binom{4}{n}}{\binom{16}{n}}\\
\\
P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{k}\cap A_{l})&=\frac{\binom{0}{n}}{\binom{16}{n}}=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we use principle of inclusion - exclusion, to find the probability that at least one group does not have any graduate student.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup A_{4})&=\binom{4}{1}P(A_{i})-\binom{4}{2}P(A_{i}\cap A_{j})+\binom{4}{3}P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A{k})-\binom{4}{4}P(A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{k}\cap A_{l})\\
\\
&=\frac{4\binom{12}{n}-6\binom{8}{n}+4\binom{4}{n}}{\binom{16}{n}}
\end{aligned}
$$

The probability of every group has at least one graduate student is $1-P(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup A_{4}))$.

$$
1-P(A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup A_{4})=1-\frac{4\binom{12}{n}-6\binom{8}{n}+4\binom{4}{n}}{\binom{16}{n}}
$$

For Q1, substitute $n=4$ to obtain $\frac{4^{4}}{\binom{16}{4}}$ (same as Your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to consider a sample space contains outcomes of all different permutations of 16 student slots ($16!$). Then the interested events are the sequence of students of the permutation of 4 graduates students ($4!$) times 4 possible slots for each graduate student in 4 groups ($4^4$) times permutation of the 12 slots for the undergraduate students ($12!$).

$$ \frac{4! \cdot (4^4) \cdot 12!}{16!}$$

, which gives same result as the formula in your Q1 part.

For Q2, it might be easier to calculate the probability of the complement event and subtract that from 1.